# Show image in SelectOneMenu Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Iam trying to display a list of currencies from a database through a drop down list , every currency has a logo

```
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{currencyController.currency}"
                                     converter="#{currencyConverter}"
                                     var="c" style="width:180px">

                        <f:selectItems value="#{currencyController.currencyList}" 
                                       var="currency"
                                       itemLabel="#{currency.currencyName}" 
                                       itemValue="#{currency}"/>

                         <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{c.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:10%">
                     
                                <p:graphicImage value="#{c.image}"
                                                cache="false"
                                                style="height:3em;width:3em"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The name is displayed fine but the problem is that the logo is not getting displayed at all

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yep your `value="#{c.image}"` must not be evaluating to a proper image should be pretty easy for you to debug esepcially looking at `p:graphicImage` examples and looking at F12 network traffic errors.